# Como faço pra usar ui-number-mask de maneira dinâmica

Tags: angularjs, input-mask

Estou guardando meu valor em um $scope:

```
$scope.quantidadeCasasDecimais = 4
```

E tentando usar este valor, porém não funciona:

```
ui-number-mask="{{quantidadeCasasDecimais}}"
```

Lembrando que se eu setar o parâmetro de maneira estática funciona:

```
ui-number-mask="4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta tirar as chaves, por se tratar de uma biblioteca já voltada pro angularjs, para mais informações acesse a documentação da biblioteca: https://assisrafael.github.io/angular-input-masks/

```
ui-number-mask="quantidadeCasasDecimais"
```

Comment: Explique porque tirando a chave resolve o problema, por favor.